# Rails render named route with correct URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following route in my rails application

```
match '/settings', to: 'Users#edit', as: 'settings'
```

And corresponding controller code

```
def edit
  @user = current_user
end

def update
  correct_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if !@user.authenticate(params[:old_password])
    flash[:error] = 'Old password did not match'
    redirect_to settings_path
  elsif @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:success] = "Settings updated"
    redirect_to settings_path
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

My edit page is as of now just a password change page, and when I visit `/settings` I see the page I'd except. When I `redirect_to settings_path`, the url remains `/settings`, which is the behavior I want.

In my `edit` template, I have code to handle object errors and render them on the page. When `render 'edit`, this code is triggered if there was an object error. If I redirect to the page, however, the code is not there. So I need to call `render 'edit'` to see the errors.

However, calling `render 'edit'` causes the URL to change to `/users/:id/edit`, which is exactly what I **don't** want. I'd like the URL to remain `/settings` after calling `render 'edit'`. How can I achieve this?

**NOTE:** I've already searched SO and other parts of the internet but have found nothing that suits my needs. There are one or two SO topics with similar issues but they all use flashing and hacky redirect-based workarounds, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would want to set up your routes like this:

```
match 'settings': 'users#edit', via: :get
match 'settings': 'users#update', via: :put
```

Then the form should be declared like this:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: settings_path %>
```

In your controller, make sure you're calling `render` like this:

```
render action: "edit"
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a bad `link_to` in your view, one using the old-style `:controller` and `:action` arguments separately instead of using `settings_path`.

Keep in mind that if there are two routes to the same controller and action pair, the first route defined has priority. Define your custom route first to ensure it's used by default.